# How to extract specific values from json string where keys are part of java object

Tags: java, json

I have a map with the generic value as json key-pair.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

and the values could be

```
<p1, {key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3...}>
```

After getting the value from the map I need to convert it into an object but not the complete object. These are all generic values and I need to fetch values that are required only by that service. For e.g.
I have 2 classes

```
class A{
    String key1;
    String key2;
}

class B{
    String key3;
}
```

So along with the key if I pass class of type `A` then it should create an object of `A` with only `key1,key2` from json and return that object. Similar is for class `B`.

My input could be `(p1,A.class)` and output is `new A(value1,value2)`.

Comment: Where is your code that parses the json and tries to extract the specific values?

Comment: l haven't written any code yet. Just thinking of some way to make it generic so that it could be used for any type of class. So far l am familiar with jackskon to convert into specific object.